# LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup with DLLs

Tags: c, winapi, dll, sdl

So here's another thread about the infamous ___tmainCRTStartup unresolved external symbol. Yes, it's about SDL again, but it's with a twist which AFAICS hasn't been covered here yet. 
Let me first clear up some parameters:

1) I am trying to build a DLL that statically links against SDL2.lib.

2) I am not using Visual Studio but Visual C and a console (first cmake, then nmake).

3) The project is entirely in C, no C++ code is in there (unless there's C++ in SDL2 but AFAIK SDL2 is completely in C)

4) All objects that are collected in SDL2.lib and the other objects are compiled using /MT, i.e. I want to link statically against the Visual C runtime (libcmt.lib).

5) SDL2.lib is then created like this:

```
link /nologo /lib /out:SDL2.lib file1.obj file2.obj....
```

6) The target DLL is linked like this:

```
link /dll /subsystem:WINDOWS /out:test.dll file1.obj file2.obj ... kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib imm32.lib winmm.lib version.lib SDL2.lib
```

What is confusing the hell out of me here is that the call above yields the following error:

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

How can this possibly happen? I clearly pass **/dll** to link.exe so why on earth is the C runtime looking for main()? It should be looking for DllMain()! A main() symbol in a DLL doesn't make any sense at all, yet I get this confusing error!

It must be something inside SDL2.lib that is causing this problem but I honestly have no clue what could force the linker to look for a main() entry point here. I mean, SDL2.lib is a linker library that should be completely **target neutral**, i.e. it should be possible to link SDL2.lib against a WinMain() executable but it should also be possible to link SDL2.lib against a DllMain() library but here it seems to refuse to be linked into a DLL!

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong here? I have searched for hours now and this totally escapes me.

**EDIT:** Interestingly, the problem does not occur when everything is compiled using /MD. It only occurs when using /MT. I'm really completely clueless as to what could be the cause here.

**EDIT2:** I've also tried to compile SDL2 with /DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED but it doesn't make the error go away.

Comment: If you're trying to create a static library from SDL2 I think you need to use lib.exe not link.exe.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo... I was using link with the /lib option. It's now corrected. I have also tested to use lib.exe directly but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: SDL has too much hanky-panky going on, necessary to make it portable across many operating systems.  You are probably fighting src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c, intended to fool the linker into believing that the entrypoint for a native Windows program is main().  That works when the sun is shining and you've got the wind in your back.  Compiling with /MT is certainly asking for a very stiff head-wind.  Use the project's mailing list, only way to get in touch with Sam Lantinga.

Comment: You could try defining a dummy main() and see what happens. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant: SDL_windows_main.c shouldn't be the culprit because it is compiled into a small separate link library named SDL2main.lib by default. As I'm not linking against this library SDL_windows_main.c cannot really mess with anything.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Funnily, even a dummy main() doesn't make the error go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost four years later I finally revisited this issue and after going through all object files to see which one was the culprit I finally found the error in `src/SDL.c`. It has these lines at the end:

```
#if defined(__WIN32__)

#if !defined(HAVE_LIBC) || (defined(__WATCOMC__) && defined(BUILD_DLL))
/* Need to include DllMain() on Watcom C for some reason.. */

BOOL APIENTRY
_DllMainCRTStartup(HANDLE hModule,
                   DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
#endif /* building DLL with Watcom C */

#endif /* __WIN32__ */
```

So SDL always defined a `_DllMainCRTStartup` symbol which seems to have confused the linker and led to the error shown in the OP. Killing the code above (or defining `HAVE_LIBC`) finally solves the problem and I can build SDL2 just fine with `/MT` (though I still don't know why compiling with `/MD` didn't cause any problems because AFAICS `_DllMainCRTStartup` will also be defined when compiling with `/MD` but it doesn't seem to cause any harm in that case).

Issue solved, finally.